# A palavra "cãi(n)do/a"

Tags: ortografia, regionalismo, gíria

Minha mãe é do Maranhão e desde pequeno usamos o adjetivo "cãi(n)do/a" (honestamente, nem sei como escrever) para fazer referência a alguém atrapalhado, abobado. Fora da família, aqui em São Paulo, nunca ouvi ninguém usando esse termo. Dia desses fui pesquisar a palavra e não a encontrei em lugar algum. A pronúncia é como em "cãibra", mas com a terminação em -inda/o. A grafia não saberia dizer se é "cãi**n**do" ou "cãido", ou qualquer outra.

Alguém saberia algo sobre? Encontrei só referências a uma determinada "D. Cãinda", o que não ajudou em nada.

Comment: Talvez venha de *cândido*: cãdido > cãido. A palavra *cândido* pode significar alguém puro, inocente, o que pode ser similar a tolo, atrapalhado, bobo, etc.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Portuguese SE, Bruno, e obrigado pela pergunta. Outra possibilidade para a origem talvez seja uma redução de "canhoto", que também pode [significar](https://dicionario.priberam.org/canhoto) "desajeitado".

Comment: Bruno e @Schilive, a *Revista Lusitana* de 1918 (vol. 21, p. 325) regista em Portugal *Cãindo* como forma popular de *Cândido*. Também encontrei *Cãindo* e *Cãinda* como nome de pessoa no Brasil (a D. Cãinda que tu encontraste é um exemplo), que deve também ser forma popular de *Cândido/a*. E para além de ’puro’ e ’inocente’, o Houaiss dá *cândido* como sinónimo de ’ingénuo’ e ’tolo’.

Comment: uau, muito interessante, pessoal. Obrigado pelas respostas! "Cândido", no sentido de ingênuo/tolo, combina bem com o significado que damos a "cãindo", de fato.

Comment: Sabe o que faria se fosse você? Ligaria para algum lugar lá no Maranhão, tipo prefeitura o escola e perguntaria. Esses usos regionais muitas vezes não se encontram em dicionários.

Comment: @Jacinto Gostaria de transformar seu comentário numa resposta? Nada melhor apareceu até agora.

Comment: Olá! Achei muito interessante essa palavra discutida. Sou do Ceará e nunca ouvi nada igual para se referir a alguém tolo/ingênuo. Essa é a riqueza da nossa língua, a variedade! Quanto à escrita, por normas da língua, seria mais correto escrever “Cãido” ou então “Câindo” e não “Cãindo”, pois já que há ~, não é necessário a letra N para tal nasalização. Fora que também entrariam outros pontos a respeito de sílabas e estrutura dos vocábulos.

Answer (score 5):

***Cãido, Cãida*** estão atestados como formas populares de ***Cândido, Cândida*** em Portugal, na *Revista Lusitana* de 1918 (vol. 21, p. 325, disponível para download no [Instituto Camões](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/conhecer/biblioteca-digital-camoes/etnologia-etnografia-tradicoes.html?limit=20&limitstart=20)):

> **Candido**, nome proprio. Fórmas populares: *Cãido, -a; Cãidlo* (Algarve)

E no Brasil, na [Revista do Instituto do Ceará de 1936](https://books.google.pt/books?id=LCg0AQAAIAAJ&q=%22mantive%20por%20isso%20a%20forma%20c%C3%A3ida%22&dq=%22mantive%20por%20isso%20a%20forma%20c%C3%A3ida%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifhpyY1sj1AhUuM-wKHV55DGEQ6AF6BAgCEAI) (mais [outro excerto](https://books.google.pt/books?id=LCg0AQAAIAAJ&q=%22C%C3%A1ndido%20Holanda%20,%20%C3%A9%20ainda%22&dq=%22C%C3%A1ndido%20Holanda%20,%20%C3%A9%20ainda%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihqJ302Mj1AhUQxoUKHdKMCRQQ6AF6BAgCEAI) para completar):

> Mantive por isso a forma *Cãida* , que é popular e familiar. Ela veio-nos através de *Cándia*, acusado por outra variante , com a metátese do *i*, normal em português.  Houve no Ceará um médico e dentista estimado, cujo nome, *Cándido Holanda*, é ainda hoje por todos pronunciado *Candi’Holanda*.

E ***cândido*** há muito que tem o significado de **’ingénuo, simples’**. Daqui para o ’atrapalhado, abobado’ do uso descrito na pergunta, não é grande salto, como o autor já observou nos comentários.

Segundo o Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002), *cândido* vem do latim *candidum*, que significava ’branco, alvo; vestido de branco; radioso, brilhante’ (*candeia* e *candeeiro* são da mesma família) e ainda ’belo, formoso, sereno; feliz, ditoso’. Em português, já em [1712 Raphael Bluteau](https://books.google.pt/books?id=7-VBAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA98&lpg=RA1-PA98&dq=%22CANDIDO,%20C%C3%A2ndido.%20Alvo.%20Branco%22&source=bl&ots=RgKgBf_Ivw&sig=ACfU3U1vKf2gAIoBCo1YSNWweh1gR1k7GQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjuj-KW3cj1AhVRzIUKHeE3BAgQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22CANDIDO%2C%20C%C3%A2ndido.%20Alvo.%20Branco%22&f=false) regista *cândido* com os significados de ’alvo, branco’ e também ’singelo, sincero, muito puro, de costumes e vida santa’. Em [1789, Moraes Silva](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kPBDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=%22singello%20simples%20ingenuo%22&source=bl&ots=EwZtvclj4N&sig=ACfU3U2EW0S0n6yFsf5Q11XeFGFekVNX0Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_rtvop8P1AhUjCGMBHavvDskQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=%22singello%20simples%20ingenuo%22&f=false) já acrescenta **’simples, ingénuo, inocente’**. Ele usa todos estes termos apreciativamente, mesmo [*ingénuo*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kPBDAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA720&lpg=RA1-PA720&dq=%22sem%20dobrez,%20n%C3%A3o%20refolhado%22&source=bl&ots=EwZtvcnnaE&sig=ACfU3U03Y7Al_03owspiG8swzjPQKTmAQQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjS5rP5sMP1AhUG4BoKHQz_CpYQ6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q=%22sem%20dobrez%2C%20n%C3%A3o%20refolhado%22&f=false), que ele define como ’sincero, singelo, sem [dobrez](https://books.google.pt/books?id=jw35ZrdRyngC&pg=PA451&lpg=PA451&dq=%22Falta%20de%20sinceridade%20do%20homem%22&source=bl&ots=fXI91x7xn0&sig=ACfU3U1iZAj5hgL9yAeOXuFiAXHfW1563A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif4aeyssP1AhVDPBoKHZuSA9gQ6AF6BAg3EAM#v=onepage&q=%22Falta%20de%20sinceridade%20do%20homem%22&f=false), não [refolhado](https://books.google.pt/books?id=rwVdAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA306&lpg=PA306&dq=%22REFOLHADO,%20adj.%20dissimulado%22&source=bl&ots=UHDC7oa3nQ&sig=ACfU3U3vu4HTXV9JosDGpYhh3g1T-aVbEQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiasI_Xy8j1AhUJ-qQKHTGTAM8Q6AF6BAgEEAM#v=onepage&q=%22REFOLHADO%2C%20adj.%20dissimulado%22&f=false)’ (links às definições no mesmo dicionário).

Basicamente, para ele, *ingénuo* é ’que não tem malícia’. E exemplos de *muito cândido* que eu encontro do século XVIII têm a ver com isso, com pessoas que levam vidas santas. Mas em exemplos do século XIX já encontro acerca de pessoas que são ingénuas no sentido de não verem as manhas dos outros (e por isso poderem deixar-se enganar); é esse o caso, como se pode ver pelo contexto, deste [“A Senhora é muito candida” (1880)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=BPhRAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA92&dq=%22senhora%20%C3%A9%20muito%20candida%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjH_Z6Vn5jzAhVP6RoKHaKeC5UQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22senhora%20%C3%A9%20muito%20candida%22&f=false) ou este [“foi muito candido ou muito politico” (1892)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=h-4rAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA62&dq=%22foi%20muito%20candido%20ou%20muito%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiq49-jlZjzAhVQecAKHSYZCdgQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22foi%20muito%20candido%20ou%20muito%22&f=false).

De fama internacional, já em 1759, o *Cândido* do romance [*Cândido ou O Otimismo* de Voltaire](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A2ndido,_ou_O_Otimismo) era um bocado bobo. Este romance serviu de inspiração à novela brasileira [*Êta Mundo Bom* (2016)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8Ata_Mundo_Bom!) e à personagem Candinho; do pouco que vi fiquei com a ideia que ele era também ingénuo e simplório; não sei se *cãido* lhe assentaria bem...

Answer (score 0):

A escrita é "caindo". O que acontece é que a pronúncia é nasalada, ou seja, é um som emitido pelo nariz, logo, a pronúncia tende a ser diferente. O mesmo ocorre com "cãibra/câimbra".

Comment: Bem-vindo, Wellington Siqueira, ao Portuguese StakExchange! Obrigado pela resposta, mas aqui se geralmente tenta usar referências nas respostas. Não és obrigado a fazer isso, mas a responde fica mais fraca. Bem-vindo e obrigado de qualquer modo.